# What is meant by a function being linear in two variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

I'm trying to understand the Mangasarian condition in the context of dynamic optimization (see [here](http://people.umass.edu/resec712/documents/Lecture8DynamicOptimization.pdf) p 8.12) and am not sure what exactly is meant by a function $f(x,u)$ being linear in $x$ and $u$. If $a$ and $b$ are fixed parameters, then I understand that $ax + bu$ is linear in both variables, and $ax^2+bu^2$ and $ax^2u^2$ are not.  But suppose:

$$f(x,u)=axu$$

Is that linear in $x$ and $u$ or not, and what test should be applied to determine this?

Comment: What you wrote is linear in both variables. Fix $x$ or fix $u$. A general bilinear model would be $f(x,u)=a+b x+c u + d xu$.

Comment: $f$ is linear in both argument (bilinear) if $f(x+by,z)=f(x,z)+bf(y,z)$ and $f(x,cy+z)=f(x,z)+cf(x,y)$ for any $x,y,z,b,c$